# Error with visibility using toggleClass and Keyframes

Tags: html, jquery, css

I´m trying to do an hamburger menu that displays the elements of the menu using keyframes. The elements are not visible as in my css there are rules for that, but when the menu is clicked appears visible at first and then begins the animation after. I have no idea where is the mistake.

You can see the demo in codepen: https://codepen.io/carlos-turpin-trives/pen/YzQLyBg

and the code:

```
 <div class="container"></div>
 <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
 <span class="top"></span><span class="middle"></span>
 <span class="bottom"></span>  
 </div>
 <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
</div>
<div class="containers">
<h1><span class="">reveal</span></h1>
<h1><span class="">reveal</span></h1>
<h1><span class="">reveal</span></h1>
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  heigh: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
}
.container p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.container a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1abc9c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 5px;
}
.container a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #1abc9c;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.35s ease;
}
.container a:hover:after, .container a:focus:after, .container a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Varela Round", serif;
}

.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
    }
  
.button_container.active .top {
  transform: translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}
.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
  .button_container:hover .middle {
  transform: scaleX(.75);
}
   .button_container.active:hover .top {
  width:100%;
}
     .button_container.active:hover .bottom {
  width:100%;
}
    .button_container:hover .top {
  -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
   transition: .1s ease-in-out;
   width: 50%; 
}
    .button_container:hover .bottom {
  -webkit-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
   transition: .1s ease-in-out;
   width: 30%; 
}
.button_container.active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #FFF;
  
}
.button_container span {
  background: #1abc9c;
  border: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 11px;
}
.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 22px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: #1abc9c;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay.open {
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.containers {
  padding: 100px 200px 400px 0;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, visibility 0.35s, height 0.35s;
}
  .containers.open {
  opacity: 0.9;
  visibility: visible;

}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;

}
h1 span {
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.text-warning-anim {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
animation: reveal 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0.5s ;
}
 
@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0,140%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {

   $(this).toggleClass('active');

   $(this).find('.button_container').removeClass('hover');
   $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
 
  $('.containers').toggleClass('open');
  $('h1 span').toggleClass("text-warning-anim");

  });
```

Comment: I goofed around a bit in your codepen and it seems like cubic-bezier is causing your issue. Removing that from the animation, it works for me. What specific purpose does it serve in your website?

Comment: Great, Lalalena!! I was worried and you solved my day! I will use it as link elements of the hamburger menu. What do you think?